# Authorize in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I want to implement a web project with ASP.NET Core, all pages of which require authorization.

I do not want to put the `Authorize` attribute on top of all controllers.

Is there a way to define this at the project level and have it applied to all pages?

Answer (score 2):

For Razor Pages, you can just add `RequireAuthorization` in your configuration file (probably `Startup.cs`) (described by [andrewlock.net](https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/)).

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // Require Authorization for all your Razor Pages
    endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
});
```

For controllers, you can do something very similar:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // Require Authorization for all your Controllers
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
});
```

Another simple solution for Controllers is a parent controller with a single `[Authorize]`:

```
[Authorize]
public class AuthorizedController : Controller
{
}
```

Then you can inherit your specific controllers, like:

```
public class MyController : AuthorizedController
{
}
```

They will all be authorized.